# Synology LAN connection

Tags: lan, synology

I have a Synology DS415+. It has two LAN with Failover and Link Aggregation Support but I have no idea what this means.

I have only one Ethernet cable out of the wall which connects the internet to one LAN port of my Synology.

Can I use the other LAN port to connect a PC that requires Ethernet connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can I use the other LAN port to connect a PC that requires Ethernet connection?

No, You can’t.  Your NAS cannot be used as a router.